# How can I get user input data from inline entity form complex and alter it before saving drupal 8

Tags: drupal

I have an inline entity form complex and I want to get form state values before submit in drupal 8. I have tried using:

```
function mymodule_inline_entity_form_entity_form_alter(&$entity_form, &$form_state)

{

if ($entity_form['#entity_type'] == 'care_giver') 

    {

    //collect values from the form
    $name = $form_state->getUserInput();

   }
}
```

I want to collected values from the inline entity form and save them to another entity programmatically.So when I try to collect data using the above code I get null results

Comment: Add a custom validation function. Like shown in this [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/22964/15055) on Drupal Answers. But I'm not sure if that also works that way for inline entity forms. Better have a decent look at the code of the Inline Entity Form module itself. Maybe there even is an element validation example.

Comment: And please try to follow [coding standards](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/coding-standards).

Comment: Any update or final solution for this?